# Calculating Expectation Value and Variance for Alternating Random Walk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

I am self teaching and i am very stuck on this question

If we have the stochastic process ${X_n : n = 0, 1, 2, . . .} $ which is a Markov chain on the integers with
$X_0 = 0$. If $|X_n|$ is even, the conditional probabilities $P(X_{n+1} = i + 1|X_n = i) = 3/4$ and
$P(X_{n+1} = i − 1|X_n = i) = 1/4$ are given, whereas if $|X_n|$ is odd, the conditional
probabilities are $P(X_{n+1} = i + 1|X_n = i) = 1/4$ and $P(X_{n+1} = i − 1|X_n = i) = 3/4$.
Calculate $E[X_n]$ and the variance $Var[X_n] = E[(X_n − E[X_n])^2].$

I know that for asymmetric random walks $X_n = X_0 + \sum ^n_{j=1} Z_j$ and the random variables (the increments) and chosen identically and independently with $P(Z_j = +a)=p $ and, $P(Z_j=-a)=1-p=q$

For the even, i let $p= 3/4 $and $ 1-p =1/4 = q$  and i have that the mean for asymmetric random walks is $E[X_n] =na(p-q)$ and variance $σ_n^2 =na^2[(p+q)-(p-q)^2]$ where $n$ is the number of steps and a is the size of the individual step. In my book its says to assume a= 1 usually.

Would really appreciate the help

Comment: You can put subscripts in braces: $X_{n+1}$.   X_{n+1}

Comment: You have incompatible assumptions, your random walk depends on odd/even state, and so  your sum of i.i.d. variables $Z_i$ does not relate.  If you want to sample the system on even slots, so $X_0, X_2, X_4, ...$ then you can get back to a (zero drift) random walk with i.i.d. increments. Or you can simply model the process by $X_n=X_0 + Z_1 + W_2 + Z_3 + W_4 + Z_5 + W_6 + ...$.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for comments. so is the mean =0?

Comment: It depends on $n$ and on $X_0$.   If $n$ is even you have $X_n=X_0+(Z_1+W_2)+...+(Z_{n-1}+W_n)$.

Comment: I was given that $X_0 = 0$. What i did was find the expectation for the odd steps and even steps and add them together. So $ (E[X_{2n+1}] =1/2n  )+ ( E[X_{2n}]=-1/2n) =0$. Is this wrong?

Comment: Indeed $E[Z_{2k+1} + W_{2k+2}]=0$ for all $k$. And of course the variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of the variances.